# How to eliminate Roxygen warning about "No name found..."?

Tags: r, roxygen, roxygen2

I'm calling roxygenize() with parameter use.Rd2 = TRUE.  I have a file testcase.R where I create a simple S3 object using R.oo.  Here's the contents of the file.  There's nothing for roxygen to do here, and it should ignore the contents:

```
library( R.oo )

setConstructorS3( "TestCase" , 
function() 
{  
    extend( Object() , "TestCase", 
            .parameters = list() ,
            .validationData = list()
          )
} )
```

And here's the error:

```
Error in parse.name(partitum) :
  (converted from warning) No name found for the following expression in E:/mypackage/R/te
stcase.R line 1:
  `library( R.oo ) . . .'
Calls: roxygenize ... <Anonymous> -> maybe.call -> do.call -> <Anonymous> -> par
se.name
```

How can I eliminate the warning?  Per suggestions in other posts, I added the following as the first line, but it didn't work:

```
 #' @nord
```

Comment: Use roxygen2. It's a small investment but worth it.

Comment: you beat me to the comment!  I just upgraded and it works great.

Comment: could you add Roxygen2 as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to Roxygen2 eliminated the error.